# node express 4 - how do I log successful requests?

Tags: node.js, logging, express

In express 4, the package morgan is used for logging. Strangely, none of the built in modes seem to log successful requests - they only log error cases. I'm using it as middleware, like so:

`app.use(morgan('dev'));`

How can I get it to print all activity going through the server, including successful requests?

Comment: Morgan should automatically log all activity. Are you saying it's not doing that? Can you provide a sample of the output you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I had to setup morgan *before* setting up my routes. Changing the order made everything work as expected

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of middleware available for logging.  At a minimum, you can do something like this:

```
app.use(function log (req, res, next) {
  console.log([req.method, req.url].join(' '));
  next();
});
```

It's entirely up to you to decide how you want to handle this.

I usually don't bother as I typically run Nginx out in front of my application servers.  If I need access logs, I just use its logs.  If I need application logs for debugging, then that's what I get out of my Node.js servers.

Comment: Thank you, great answer, but I was more curious about how to get morgan to do this, since it seems to be the officially supported logging utility.

Comment: @ZECTBynmo I've never used Morgan, but based on the documentation and what you have up there, it should work.  If it isn't working, there may be something wrong with your server.  Also, there is no downside to using other modules that aren't in the expressjs GitHub repo.  The middleware pattern used by Express came from Connect and is standardized pretty much everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware which middleware doesn't contain the next() invocation of the 'next' middleware.

For example, the 'serve-static' middleware does not invoke next() on success. It only invokes next() on certain error conditions.  Therefore, in order to log success requests, you need to use() 'morgan' before 'serveStatic'